# Column operation in python

Tags: python

I have a file as below (m,deg,deg)

```
0   0       5
10  0.65    12
20  0.61    14
30  0.53    3
40  0.54    6
```

And I want to do operation between rows in same column in python for example third column diff between row, example  (12-5) (14-12) (3-14) (6-3) and so on

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: please edit your post and format your code......!

Comment: I am assuming you mean: [[`0, 0, 5], [10, 0.65, 12], [20, 0.61, 14], [30, 0.53, 3], [40, 0.54, 6]]` with the columns being: m, deg, deg? And you want row/col operations?

Comment: yes that what I mean

Comment: Have a look at the [pandas library](http://pandas.pydata.org/) - it is designed to handle such tasks.

Comment: `numpy` is worth checking out as well. All functions are optimized in the C level

Answer (score 2):

Start by iterating over the file a line at a time, discarding the header line.

Split each line on white space, and pull the third column out of every line and convert it to an int (which is the only field you seem to care about).

Zip the result with itself offset by one, map over the output and subtract - this is so we can subtract the first row from the second, the second from the third and so on.

```
with open("tab-separated-values") as tsv:
    splitLines = [line.split() for line in tsv]  
    degs = [int(line[2]) for line in splitLines[1:]]
    print [deg[1] - deg[0] for deg in zip(degs, degs[1:])]
```

Comment: Can you explain your solution instead of just providing a code snippet?

Comment: @Arnon explanation added

Comment: George Simms this work for my file fornmate file up

Comment: @Majid can you upvote/mark as correct then?

Comment: @George Simms correction has been made

Comment: @Majid does this solution work? If so, mark the answer as correct. If not, why not?

Comment: `zip(degs, degs[1:])` should be enough. From the docs about `zip`: The returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.

Comment: @user38034 edited accordingly

Comment: @George Simms , I am beginer with PYTHON .. In my case I have to read from Table with formate I show it in my Question... I will try to work with youre codes, Thanks a lot

Comment: mytable =table();
 for x in rows_of(mytable):
    splitLines = [line.split() for line in mytable]  
    degs = [int(line[2]) for line in splitLines[1:]]
    print [deg[1] - deg[0] for deg in zip(degs, degs[1:])]

Comment: this what I try but does not work

Comment: Right. What does `rows_of` return?